# After a registration getting logged out

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.3

I am creating an admin panel where admin can create an user. I have used laravel default registration system. I have modified the RegisterController little. The user is being created successfully. But the problem is after creating user the admin is getting logged out. What is the problem?
Here are my files. I am using laravel 5.3

> web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/admin/user/register','Auth\CreateUserController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('/admin/user/register','Auth\CreateUserController@register');
});
```

> CreateUserController

```
class CreateUserController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;
    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->check()) return '/admin/index';
        else if(Auth::guard('employee')->check()) return '/employee/dashboard';
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'district' => 'required',
            'gender' => 'required',
            'mobile' => 'required',
        ]);
    }
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'district' =>$data['district'],
            'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
            'gender'=>$data['gender'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to overwrite **register** function too

Comment: just removed this lines $this->guard()->login($user); and it worked :) thank you